# Using for loop iteration with If statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list of multiple items. Need to create a loop that finds an item from the list and prints it out.
If item not found prints out only once that it hasn't been found.

```
 for x in range(len(regs)):
    rex = regs[x]
    if re.match(rex,hostname):
        print (dev[x],'Regex matched')
        break
    else:
        print('wrong format')
```

Currently it prints out multiple times that it hasn't been found.
When it matches the regex it prints out at the end. 
I only want the If Else to prints "wrong format" once.

currently prints out  wrong format wrong format wrong format wrong format
wrong format wrong format wrong format "DeviceX Regex matched"

Comment: a simple solution will be to use a flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printed multiple times, because there are multiple times where the current value does not match. A simple way to fix this is to use a flag, like so:

```
value_found = False 

for x in range(len(regs)):
    rex = regs[x]
    if re.match(rex,hostname):
        print (dev[x],'Regex matched')
        value_found = True
        break

if not value_found:
    print('wrong_format')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `else` with `for`.

As you are breaking out of the for loop as soon as you find one item, the below code will work fine:

```
for x in range(len(regs)):
    rex = regs[x]
    if re.match(rex,hostname):
        print (dev[x],'Regex matched')
        break
else:
    # Does not execute only when a break statement
    # is executed inside the for loop.
    print('wrong format')
```

Comment: just a gentle reminder.. it's not a good practice to use for-else construct but in this case its fine I guess

Comment: Agreed! But in this short and simple code, I think it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a flag variable as follows.

```py
matched = False
for x in range(len(regs)):
    rex = regs[x]
    if re.match(rex, hostname):
        print(dev[x], "Regex matched!")
        matched = True
        break
if not matched:
    print("Wrong format")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
flag = 0     
for x in range(len(regs)):
    rex = regs[x]
    if re.match(rex, hostname):
        print(dev[x], 'Regex matched')
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 0:
    print('wrong format')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it shorter using comprehensive list such as:

```
if len([r for r in regs if re.match(r, hostname)]) == 1:
  print(dev[regs.index([r for r in regs if re.match(r, hostname)][0])], 'Regex matched')
else:
  print('not found')
```

Comment: This code does not work if multiple elements match. The first condition should be `len(...) >= 1`. And you would probably also need to change the statement in the `print`.